# Handle inline polymorphism in typescript

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

Have an implementation of polymorphism in typescript.

```
enum empType {
   developer = '1',
   qa = '2',
   manager = '3'
}

interface IEmployee {
   type: empType;
   ID: string;
   name: string;
   projectId: string;
}

interface IEmployeeDeveloper extends IEmployee {
   type: empType.developer;
   featureID: string;
   deadline: string;
}

interface IEmployeeQa extends IEmployee {
   type: empType.qa;
   bugCount: number;
}

interface IEmployeeManager extends IEmployee {
   type: empType. manager;
   reporteeIDs: string[];
}
```

If I need to have a config data holding a list of such employees

```
let employees: Record<string, IEmployee> = {
  'tom': {
      type: empType.developer,
      ID: '1',
      name: 'tom',
      projectId: '123',
      featureID: 'xxx',
      deadline: '01/01/2023'
   },
   'sham': {
      type: empType.qa,
      ID: '12',
      name: 'sham',
      projectId: '123',
      bugCount: 10000
   },
   'harry': {
      type: empType.manager,
      ID: '3',
      name: 'harry',
      projectId: '123',
      reporteeIDs: ['1', '2']
   },
}
```

While trying to compile the code, I am getting such error.

```
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS2322: Type '{ type: empType.developer; ID: string; name: string; projectId: string; featureID: string; deadline: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IEmployee'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'featureID' does not exist in type 'IEmployee'.

featureID: 'xxx',
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error TS2322: Type '{ type: empType.qa; ID: string; name: string; projectId: string; bugCount: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IEmployee'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bugCount' does not exist in type 'IEmployee'.

bugCount: 10000,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 error TS2322: Type '{ type: empType.manager; ID: string; name: string; projectId: string; reporteeIDs: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IEmployee'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'reporteeIDs' does not exist in type 'IEmployee'.

reporteeIDs: ['1', '2'],
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If instead we try to initialize like this

```
let employees: Record<string, any> = /same config code as above/
```

Then I am able to compile.
However I want my variables to be properly typed and I do not prefer using **any** in my type definition.

Another way is

```
let employees: Record<string, IEmployee | IEmployeeDeveloper | IEmployeeQa | IEmployeeManager> = /same config code as above/
```

The issue with this is that in near future I will create many types of **IEmployee**. Then I will have to change the type of employees everytime I do such a thing. Also need to update all those place where I am using this variables.

How can we handle such scenarios in typescript.

Comment: See here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html Search specifically on `function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
  return new c();` for inspiration.
}

Comment: I think the best way is to use a union, with a type alias `type Employee = IEmployee | IEmployeeDeveloper | IEmployeeQa | IEmployeeManager` so you only need to change one place when adding a new type and use `Employee` anywhere where you need the union

Comment: You can get around excess property checks by either assigning to an extra variable, or by using a type assertion But if you want those subtype properties checked a union is the best way to go.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Right it's been a while for me. Been off doing too much Java/Python of late. Forgot about declaring a type as Eduard posted below. That looks a plausible solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it using Union Types.
[Read more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types)

```
type EmployeeItem = IEmployeeDeveloper | IEmployeeQa | IEmployeeManager;

let employees: Record<string, EmployeeItem> = {
  'tom': {
      type: empType.developer,
      ID: '1',
      name: 'tom',
      projectId: '123',
      featureID: 'xxx',
      deadline: '01/01/2023'
   },
   'sham': {
      type: empType.qa,
      ID: '12',
      name: 'sham',
      projectId: '123',
      bugCount: 10000
   },
   'harry': {
      type: empType.manager,
      ID: '3',
      name: 'harry',
      projectId: '123',
      reporteeIDs: ['1', '2']
   },
}
```